# closed-form integral of $\ln((x+1)^{1/n}+(x)^{1/n})$

Tags: calculus, integration

I was solving the integral $$\int\ln\left((x+1)^{1/n}+(x)^{1/n}\right)dx$$ for the case $n=2$ and got $x\left(\ln{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}\right)+\frac12\Big(\ln\left(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}\right)-\sqrt{x^2+x}\Big)+C$
This had me wondering if there was a similar pattern for the other antiderivatives, like would the antiderivative for $n=3$ be $x\left(\ln{(x+1)^{1/3}+(x)^{1/3}}\right)+\frac13\bigg(\ln\Big((x+1)^{1/3}+(x)^{1/3}\Big)-\big(x^2+x\big)^{1/3}\bigg)+C$ ?

**TL;DR: Is there a *closed form* in terms of $x$ and $n$? Is it $x\left(\ln{(x+1)^{1/3}+(x)^{1/3}}\right)+\frac{1}{n}\bigg(\ln\Big((x+1)^{1/n}+(x)^{1/n}\Big)-\big(x^2+x\big)^{1/n}\bigg)+C$ ? Or something completely different?**

Note: I *tried* doing the antiderivative for $n=3$, but I was *so disorganized* that I *ran out of paper*. Also, sorry if this is formatted weirdly, I am new to MathJax, so anything that would make this look better would be awesome.

Comment: Seems to be false. (Calculating in Mathematica) with $n=2$ I get expression with `ArcSinh`, larger odd $n$ values I get expression with `AppellF1`, and larger even $n$ values I get expression with `Hypergeometric2F1` and `Beta`.

Comment: Although the expression looks like an alternative sign sum. No idea why there are distinction between $n$ odd (`AppellF1`) and $n$ even (`Hypergeometric2F1`), though.

Comment: @user202729 weird, i didn't get that i used an integral calculator and i got the answer that i got and i plugged it into desmos, and got the same thing, verifying it by taking the integral defind from 0 to x of f(t)dt, and it gave me the same graph of my answer. Did you plug in something else?

Comment: [Wolfram|Alpha link for n=2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BLog%5B(x%2B1)%5E(1%2F2)+%2B+x%5E(1%2F2)%5D,+x%5D).

Comment: @user202729 SORRY, I FORGOT PART OF THE INTEGRAL, LOL.

Comment: Something went wrong with the LaTeX? Anyway express in log functions the integral result looks like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=TrigToExp@Integrate%5BLog%5B(x%2B1)%5E(1%2F2)+%2B+x%5E(1%2F2)%5D,+x%5D). As you can see when I replace $2$ by $3$ ([link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=TrigToExp@Integrate%5BLog%5B(x%2B1)%5E(1%2F3)+%2B+x%5E(1%2F3)%5D,+x%5D)) I get Appell $F_1$ functions.

Comment: @user202729 lol I have no idea what Appell functions are, I _just_ finished calc 2 and used integration by parts and substitution (for case n=2) and got this, and made u equal to the original function, and dv equal to 1, and then used substituted y=sqrt(x/(x+1))

Comment: So, without those functions (Appell, Hypergeometric) the answer is no.

Comment: @user202729 so do you have to add an answer so I can close this or should I leave this open? I've never gotten to a question without an answer on MSE before lol.

Comment: @user202729 also arcsinh(x) = ln(x + sqrt(1+x^2) -_-

Comment: @user202729 meaning that you CAN get ln in the antiderivative.

Comment: Sorry, no. "Because W|A can't reduce it, then it can't be reduced" is not a proof. I'll leave the work of proving it is not reducible in general case to someone else.

Comment: @user202729 I meant just for the case n=2, lol not the general, because i thought you were referring to my antiderivative for n=2, but i definitely agree that it wasn't a proof, it was just a statement.